# Can you say "I have worked there for ten years" when that is no longer the case but still holds relevance at the moment of utterance?

Tags: present-perfect

[possible context: they have fired me from the company and I'm sharing that info with a friend, let's say there's some resentment]. Is the statement in the title grammatically sanctioned by a usage of the present perfect tense related to "relevance at the moment of speaking"?

Comment: When something is no longer the case, we generally use the simple past.

Comment: You cannot, because *have* is a present tense, just like "I have a dog", even if it's "have worked".

Answer (score 1):

No. It means you still work there.

You could use it in the context of a story told in the present but about the past:

> So then they fire me without warning. And at this point I've worked there for ten years!